# Adjective for object that makes another obsolete

Tags: adjectives, programming

This is for a relation between two objects that have a parent-children relationship.

In this particular case, I am keeping a list of addresses that belong to users. When one user modifies their address, the system marks the old address as obsolete and creates a new one. My question is how to describe this relationship using one adjective. The nuance that is more important for me is the fact that the old one is obsolete and that the new one replaced it (although it can also be made obsolete by a newer register). I thought some possibilities.

The old address sees the new one as its:

- Succeeder
- Subsequent
- Superseder
- Replacer
- Etc.

The new address sees the old one as its:

- Former
- Prior
- Etc.

Comment: I would say **predecessor** and **successor**.

Comment: I thought about that two adjectives, @MaxWilliams, but in my opinion, they indicate that one is after the other but they say nothing about the fact that one replaces the other.

Comment: I disagree - read the definition of "succeed" here http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succeeds

Comment: You are true. Thank you. Would you mind to turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say **successor** and **predecessor**, meaning one who *succeeds another*, or is *succeeded by another*, respectively, with the verb **"succeed"** meaning *"to replace, or follow on from"* here.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succeed

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predecessor

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/successor

Note that you would say that one is the successor **to** the other, or the predecessor **to**  the other, eg *"The iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus jointly serve as successors to the iPhone 5c and iPhone 5s."* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_6

Comment: Great response. And thank you for the tip about the preposition. I didn't think about.